# Calculated table column data - better to calculate on the server or on the client side?

Tags: django, database, material-ui, calculated-columns

I have a ~20 column table where half of the columns consist of data from my database and the other half are simple calculated values based on two of the data columns (e.g "Costs", "Revenue" column from db and a "Profit" column I would have to calculate).

How do I go about deciding when it would be best to calculate my calculated columns on the server vs on the client side?  Originally I was going to calculate it on the server (Django backend) but in an MUI Datagrid example they show a column being calculated based off two other columns.

Some points about the project that make me think frontend over backend:

- All of the data calculations are used for read only data (won't have to validate on the backend)
- All of the calculated columns are simple calculations (one column subtracted by another or divided by another)
- I'm already sending all of the data being used for calulcations to the client

Comment: See, it depends on the use case. If the data is called frequently, then it would be better to calculate these values on the client side. If it is not frequently accessed, then you can use the server, but IMO it would be better to calculate them on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

If simply, depends on what youre valuing more: business logic separation or response time.

If you value your business logic to stay in one place for any possible future change (for example, you need to calculate annual revenue differently) then it's better to leave this code server side in predetermined business folder.

If you value response time, less actions on server side means less time to generate response and handle more clients. But this is more preferable when actions take significant portion of request time.

Personally, I use both of them and choose depending on calculation complexity. In your case i'd suggest server side.